# SQL query gives me random order even with an ORDER BY clause on server but not localhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this query in Eloquent (Laravel)

```
$cats = App\Category::leftJoin('categories as b', 'categories.cat_parent', 'b.id')
        ->orderBy('b.id')
        ->get([
            'b.id as father_id',
            'categories.img as img',
            'b.descr as child_descr',
            'categories.id as child_id',
            'categories.descr as father_descr'
        ]);
```

which always gives me the same order when rendered in my view on localhost but when I go to the website, the order changes after each refresh.

What the * is going on ? Can anyone please help me to fix this ?

Both localhost and server use MySQL.

Table categories is defined as (id, descr, cat_parent, img, slug).

Comment: Can you get the SQL query as an output for debug purpose?

Comment: Solved :-) thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sorting by one key `b.id`.  Given that this is called "father_id", I speculate that multiple rows have the same value for `b_id`.

Sorting in SQL is not stable.  That means that the ordering of values with the same keys is not guaranteed -- and can even change from one call to the next.  Why is ordering not stable?  That is simple:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no "natural" ordering for the rows, apart from the explicitly specified keys.

I would suggest that you introduce a stable sort by including a second key.  I don't know what this would be, but I might speculate that `child_id` would uniquely identify each row and hence make the sort stable.